# How do I render my items#show partial within a user profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Good morning everyone! I am working on a rails assignment, and I am having some trouble rendering my items partial within a user profile. I believe the problem is that the @item variable is not initializing when within the user's views? Whenever I add a new item to a user's list, it should be attributed to him/her, and show up. At this point, I know the item is being created and specific to the user, but does not show. Here is some of my code:

Item Model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :items
end
```

Items Controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:name))
    @item.user_id = @user.id
     if @item.save
       flash[:notice] = "Item was saved."
       redirect_to [@user, @item]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the item. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
   end

   def show
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @item = Item.find(params[:id])
   end
end
```

Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @item = @user.items
  end

  private
   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
   end
end
```

_item.html.erb partial:

```
<%= @item.name %>
<br>
```

**At this point, it only shows item on the profile view.**

User#show:

```
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 lead">User profile<hr></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle avatar avatar-original" style="-webkit-user-select:none;
              display:block; margin:auto;" src="http://robohash.org/sitsequiquia.png?size=120x120">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h1 class="only-bottom-margin"><%= @user.email%></h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <span class="text-muted">Name:</span> <%= @user.name%><br>
                  <span class="text-muted">Id:</span> <%= @user.id %><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <h2>User's To-Do List</h2>
                  <%= render '/items/item' %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help, I couldn't have gone this far without the SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the code like this:

users_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @items = @user.items
end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <h2>User's To-Do List</h2>
    <%= render partial: 'items/item', locals: {items: @items} %>
</div>
```

itemss/_item.html.erb

```
<% items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I hope this will help you.

**Users Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @items = @user.items
  end

  private
   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
   end
end
```

**_item.html.erb** partial:

```
<% @items.blank? %>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <%= item.name %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
 <h2> No Items Found. </h2>
<% end %>
```

**User#show:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h2>User's To-Do List</h2>
  <%= render 'items/item', object: @items %>
</div>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Comment: I think you have missed `end`, please cross check the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following:

**users_controller.rb**

```
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @items = @user.items
 end
```

**_item.html.erb**

```
 <% unless items.blank? %>
   <% items.each do |it| %>
     <%= it.name %>
     <br/>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
 <%= render 'items/item', items: @items %>
```

Comment: No change unfortunately